# How to use "myself" as a reflexive pronoun?

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

in the phrase "I________ cooked the dinner because my wife was sick" which *reflexive pronoun* should I use between the words **I** and **cooked**?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "myself" in your example sentence, but it is not reflexive:

> "I myself cooked the dinner because my wife was sick"

That is an **emphatic** use of the pronoun:
[American Heritage Dictionary "myself" (1b)](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=myself)

> b. Used for emphasis: *I **myself** was certain of the facts.*

That same dictionary definition shows a reflexive use, where "myself" is the indirect object of the verb:

> a. Used reflexively as the direct or indirect object of a verb or as the object of a preposition:
>    *I bought **myself** a new car*.

A **reflexive** example related to your original sentence would be

> "I cooked dinner for **myself** because my wife was sick."

Comment: Another **reflexive** example: "I cooked myself some dinner". This is exactly equivalent to "I cooked some dinner for myself".